# How can I move a vehicle using speed and steering angle?

Tags: 2d, mathematics, movement, python, coordinates

I want to drive a vehicle in x and y coordinate area with range from (0,0) to (6000,5000). I am using Visual Components (using Python API).

On input I have **speed** data and **steering angle** of wheels from Simulink. For example speed of 30 (0.25 m/sec) with the steering angle of wheels from 35 to -35.

I can use something like `x = speed * COS( steeringAngle )` and `y = speed * SIN( steeringAngle )` while adding up the values of x and y together respectively for each loop.

But the problem is it goes in one direction. If the vehicle turn and comes to area below the value of current x and y. I don't know how to actually get the right x and y value when the turn is so much that it goes to reduced values of x and y. A concept photo is attached. Anyone knows how to solve this?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Speed= [1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000] #Incoming Speed
  Angle= [0,0,0,10,0,0,-20,-20,0,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35] #Incoming Angle
  item = app.findComponent('Ball') #Find component in VC
  delay(0.1)

  newposition = [10,2500,0,90,0,180] #New position array
  x = newposition[0]
  y = newposition[1]
  z = newposition[2]
  w = newposition[3]
  p = newposition[4]
  r = newposition[5]   #wpr is yaw, pitch, roll
  Xold=0
  Yold=2500
  Rold=0     #store x y and r

  for s, a in zip(Speed, Angle):        #get values from array
    delay(1)
    print "(Speed, Angle) ->",(s, a)
    x=s
    y=Yold
    r=a         #just store

    rad=math.radians(a)
    x=math.cos(rad)*s
    y=math.sin(rad)*s           #convert to radians

    Xold=Xold+x
    Yold=Yold+y
    Rold=Rold+r              #add to prev value
    x=Xold
    y=Yold
    r=Rold
    print x,y,r

    mtx = item.PositionMatrix         #get position of BALL
    mtx.P = vcVector.new(x,y,z)   #Position
    mtx.WPR = vcVector.new(w,p,r) #Orientation as yaw,pitch,roll
    item.PositionMatrix = mtx             #store new location
    item.update()
    app.render()
```

Comment: It looks like you might need to separate the concept of "steering wheel angle" - the amount of turn you're *adding* - from the concept of "heading" - the direction you're currently travelling in. Your velocity vector calculation is correct for a heading angle, but it looks like your input is a steering angle, which may act more like the derivative of your heading, depending on your control model.

Comment: I have simply a speed data which can be just taken as a forward movement. Another input is simply the angle of the wheel in - and + degrees where 0 is the non-turned wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to create a steering effect. Inorder to achieve that you will have increase/decrease the value of the angle depending on input. Like so

```
    public float steeringSensitivity = 2;
    float angle = 0;
    public float speed = 4;
    void Update() {
        float direction = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        if (direction < 0) {
            angle -= steeringSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if(direction > 0) {
            angle += steeringSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3 (speed * Mathf.Cos( angle), speed * Mathf.Sin(angle), 0);
        transform.position += offset * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Comment: I already have incoming steering angle between +/-35. The speed is coming along at the same time. But I want to move it in X and Y. Eg you have the vehicle currently on 3000,2000 position and some angle. Now if the incoming angle is 200 degrees, So obviously it will go in back direction after turning 200 degrees with some speed. So I have problem detecting the new X and Y position. Eg X and Y should be something like 3200,1800 because of almost 180 turn. How to get this value if the angle is such that the new position is then reduced X and Y value. How would I actually know the right position?

Comment: So want to calculate the new position, given an angle and speed? The way to calculate the new position is to do something like
`Vector3 newPosition = transform.position + new Vector3 (speed * Mathf.Cos( Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle), speed * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle), 0);`

Given the angle is in degrees, otherwide you won't need the Deg2Rad multiplication

Comment: Yes it seems to work somewhat.    
Thank you.     
But the main problem is still there.    Since I am moving in x and y axis, the increment is always linear. Like if the angle is 170 degrees it should be detected and the vehicle should go towards the -X axis because of near 180 turn. How to do this?

Comment: In my (python) code, I am not fully sure but the negative in Y axis works as it uses sine. But X is cosine so there is no negative in that and it always go increasing. I think it might be fine with Y to get reduced with angle but X stays positive. How this "driving" can be achieved in X-Y axis when only speed and angle is there?

Comment: Copy-paste the code you are using. There could be a mistake.

Comment: I have put the code in an ANSWER. Please check.

Comment: @Haroon Please use answer posts as answers. To add more details, please use the _edit_ feature of the question and add the new details there.

Comment: @Aj_ Check the code in question please.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the negative angle values. Try converting your negative values to the positive equivalent and check. For example -20 would become 340 (360-20) and -90 would be 270 (360-90)
You can make a function that runs through the array and convert all the negative values to positives before passing it to the trigonometry functions

Comment: No, having NO negative values is the problem I think. I can drive the BALL in X and Y but the problem is this all is increasing linearly. If the Ball turns 5 times 35 degrees its a total turn of 175 degrees. Which actually mean it would go in the BACK direction (towards - x axis). But x=math.cos(rad)*s would always give a + value because of the COSINE. I am confused how to make this BALL drive with speed and angle. The problem lies if it turns so much that it faces back side.

Comment: _"But x=math.cos(rad)*s would always give a + value because of the COSINE"_ - It shouldn't. That's not how cos in python works. It will give you negative values. Now, I don't think the problem is on the python side. You said you were using VisualComponents API; I suggest you ask this on their forums.

Comment: No, the program is Visual Components but I am using the Python API inside it. So everything I am doing is the Python. I just dont know how to move properly something in XY coordinate with just speed and angle given.

Comment: Ah, I miss read that. Still you'll have better luck asking this on the Visual Components forum.

Comment: Yes I asked it there as well and still waiting for a proper answer. But since this is Python and Mathematics/Geometry related so I asked it here. Thank you for the help, I hope I can find some working solution.